# How to left align in CsvLayout

Tags: c#, nlog

I found that the message for csv format is a number, and the format will be right-aligned.
Moreover, if message is contain nonnumeric, the format will be left-aligned.
Is there a way to unify the format.
For example [Screenshots of my excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWyaj.png)
The following is my NLog.config

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
  <time type="AccurateLocal" />
  <variable name="LogExpectedValue" value="" />
  <variable name="LogActualValue" value="" />
  <targets async="true">
    <target name="ReportFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="Report/${logger}_${date:format=yyyy_MM_dd_HH}.csv" ncoding="utf-8"
            archiveAboveSize="50000000"
            archiveNumbering="Sequence"
            keepFileOpen="false"
            autoFlush="true"
            maxArchiveFiles="3">
      <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout" withheader="true">
        <column name="ActualValue" layout="${var:LogActualValue:alignmentOnTruncation=left}" />
        <column name="ExpectedValue" layout="${var:LogExpectedValue:alignmentOnTruncation=left}" />
      </layout>
    </target>

  </targets>


  <rules>
    <logger name="Report" levels="Trace" writeTo="ReportFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking. A “CSV” format has nothing to do with how individual fields are aligned. You can certainly “align” the text data fields in the CSV file if you wanted, however, this may require some extra work when reading the file. I suggest you peruse the SO [tour] section as it shows how SO works. The [ask] section may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any point aligning data in a CSV because it's delimiter separated rather than fixed width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to wrap your CSV data with an excel function, it is messy and you will need to change your delimiters in this case.

This excel function changes numerics to text and pads with leading zeros to make it 6 digits.

=TEXT(123,"00000") where 123 is your data.

So when you export your data you will need something like this (depending on yr language)

string sOutput = "=TEXT(" & [Your data] & "," & chr(34) & "00000" & chr(34) & ")"

Try using a tab delimited file with no quotes.

An easier answer is to precede your number with a text character if possible.

Comment: Thanks your reply, I think this question is I am not familiar the excel.